# ACF get custom fields for a tag

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF to create new custom fields to include more info in tags. Then I want to retrieve in the tag page like this:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$posts_ids = isset ($term_id) ? get_fields('articulos_destacados', 'taxonomy_'.$term_id, false) : null;
```

But nothing is retrieved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$term_id` will always return as set, since get_queried_object if nothing is found returns null, so therefore it's still set.  Also, `get_fields` can accept the term object.  So you don't need the term_id.

Comment: $term = get_queried_object();
$posts_ids = isset ($term_id) ? get_field('articulos_destacados', $term) : null;

I've also try this, but I get an error saying there is no 'articulos_destacados' field (it is the one I've defined in ACF).

Comment: Do a var_dump( get_fields($term) ) and see what is returned

Comment: It worked like this:

$term = get_queried_object(); 
$posts_ids = get_fields('term_'.$term->term_id, false);

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

in ACF you should call it **prefixed** by **taxonomy name** before the **term_id**

Tags (post_tag):
`get_fields('field_name', 'post_tag_'.$term_id, false)`

Categories (category):
`get_fields('field_name', 'category_'.$cat_id, false)`

**The sloution to your code:**

`$posts_ids = isset ($term_id) ? get_fields('articulos_destacados', 'post_tag_'.$term_id, false) : null;`